# How to adjust line wrap limit (maxmum line length)?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

There are various ON/OFF line wrapping options under the Code Style settings, but I don't see where to adjust the limit. Say, I want 120 characters instead of 80.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: specify the each hard wrap value for each file type]

specify each hard wrap value for each file type. hope this will help anyone looking for hard wrap change. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 12):

It is there, you just missed it:
[image: Settings]

Comment: Aww, I was looking under Java, not in the parent category. Thanks!

Comment: tried this but its not wrapping . I am using android studio 3.4.2